# Connect MSql RDS instance with Zapier

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, zapier

I am trying to connect my RDS DB instance with Zapier. I have my test instance connected, but I can't connect my production instance because it does not have public access. Is there any way to connect without changing the public access?

I'am using rds-ca-2019 ssl certificates, i don't know if the topic can go there. I have tried using the .pem that AWS has provided me but I am still the same

Answer (score 0):

For accessing RDS in private subnets, you could use bastion host on public subnet as SSH tunnel to the RDS instance.

https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux

this way you keep the RDS non-publicly-accessible.

Comment: But that would work in AWS internally, right? What I need is to connect to an external tool that is waiting for a database instance.

Comment: No, ssh tunnel will work for any external tool that supports ssh tunneling. such as DBeaver, (or even your terminal), etc. Im not sure zapier supports it though